# Adding Google maps inside a modal in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have a working distance calculator, which I use with Google API. Because this takes a lot of space on my website, I decided to put it inside a Modal.

The problem is that the Map itself disappears and the calculations doesn't work anymore.. See screenshot.

[image]

And when I use this calculator in an empty HTML file without a modal, it  does work.

[image]

So my modal code is:

```
<button style="margin:7px 15px 17px 0;" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Bereken nu met korting!</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                <label for="start">Start: </label>
                <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />
                <label for="end">End: </label>
                <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>
                <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
                <input type="text" name="durationH" id="timeH" readonly="true" />
                <input type="text" name="durationM" id="timeM" readonly="true" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="map_canvas"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the JS I use is:

```
var directionDisplay;
var map;

function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var melbourne = new google.maps.LatLng(51.6904085, 5.29543006);
var myOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: melbourne
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function calcRoute() {
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");
var hours = document.getElementById("timeH");
var minutes = document.getElementById("timeM");

var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
        <!-- Added this myself-->
        hours.value = parseInt( response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 3600) % 24;
        minutes.value = parseInt( response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 60) % 60;
        <!-- END Adding-->
    }
});
}
```

CSS is simple:

```
#map_canvas {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are you including the G. Maps JS? Errors in the console? Please add more details.

Comment: I fixed it with @Murali's help. Normally I call the Initialize() function in the body, but this did not work for me. So I just added Initialize(); in the JS script and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <button style="margin:7px 15px 17px 0;" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Bereken nu met korting!</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        <label for="start">Start: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />
                        <label for="end">End: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>
                        <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
                        <input type="text" name="durationH" id="timeH" readonly="true" />
                        <input type="text" name="durationM" id="timeM" readonly="true" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="map_canvas"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        var directionDisplay;
        var map;
        initialize()    
        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var melbourne = new google.maps.LatLng(51.6904085, 5.29543006);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom:12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: melbourne
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
            var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
            var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");
            var hours = document.getElementById("timeH");
            var minutes = document.getElementById("timeM");
//after click cacl call to google maps size reset
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
            var request = {
                origin:start,
                destination:end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;

                    hours.value = parseInt( response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 3600) % 24;
                    minutes.value = parseInt( response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 60) % 60;
                    <!-- END Adding-->
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Oké that did work, but it has some side effects, but I can fix that. What did I forgot in my code? Did I call the Initialize() function incorrect?

Comment: Jep, I forgot the Initialize() function. Thanks :)

Comment: Just one last question: the maps is greyed out. If I open the console in chrome, the greying disappears.. any ideas?

Comment: glad to help you.I made changes in ans.now its working as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var map;
   var markers = [];
   var gLocation; //geo location of the customer
   var labels ='Taxi';
   var markerStart;
   var markerEnd;
   var directionsDisplay;
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    function initialize() {
     directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
     polylineOptions: {
       strokeColor: "purple"
     }
   });
     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     var mapProp = {
     center:new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("startLat").value, document.getElementById("startLong").value),
     zoom:12,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
     var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
     centerControlDiv.index = 1;
     centerControlDiv.style['padding-top'] = '10px';
     map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
     var infowindowStart = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: 'Start'
     });
     var infowindowEnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: 'End'
     });
     markerStart = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("startLat").value, document.getElementById("startLong").value),
       map: map
       });
     markerStart.setVisible(false);
     infowindowStart.open(map, markerStart);
     markerEnd = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("endLat").value, document.getElementById("endLong").value),
       map: map
       });
     markerEnd.setVisible(false);
       infowindowEnd.open(map, markerEnd);
       markers.push(markerStart);
       markers.push(markerEnd);
       calcRoute(document.getElementById("startLat").value, document.getElementById("startLong").value,document.getElementById("endLat").value, document.getElementById("endLong").value);
   }
   function calcRoute(startLat,startLong,endLat,endLong) {
         var start = new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong);
         var end = new google.maps.LatLng(endLat, endLong);
         var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
         bounds.extend(start);
         bounds.extend(end);
         map.fitBounds(bounds);
         var request = {
             origin: start,
             destination: end,
             travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
         };
         directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                 directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                 var distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
                 var distanceKm = (distance/1000).toFixed(0);
                 var distanceM = (distance%1000).toFixed(0);
                 var duration = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
                 var durationHrs = (duration/3600).toFixed(0);
                 var durationMins = (duration%3600/60).toFixed(0);
                 document.getElementById('distance_duration').innerHTML ="Distance: "+distanceKm+"Km "+distanceM+"m. Duration: "+durationHrs+"Hrs "+durationMins+ "mins.";
             } else {
                 alert("Directions Request from " + start.toUrlValue(6) + " to " + end.toUrlValue(6) + " failed: " + status);
             }
         });

         
   }
    function sendData(startLat,startLong,endLat,endLong){
      document.getElementById("startLat").value=String(startLat);
      document.getElementById("startLong").value=String(startLong);
      document.getElementById("endLat").value=String(endLat);
      document.getElementById("endLong").value=String(endLong);
      
    }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" >
            <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white;">
                
                    <div class="panel panel-primary" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">My Hires</div>
       <table class="table table-condensed">
        <th>Tour ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Passenger Name</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>No of Passengers</th>
        <th>Charges</th>
        <tr >
         <td>1</td>
         <td>02-03-2015</td>
         <td>01:12</td>
         <td>Bob</td>
         <td>+94789456225</td>
         <td>$1200</td>
         <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="sendData('7.866383', '79.895345','7.912803', '80.798538');setTimeout(initialize, 500);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Map</a></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                        </div>
                <!--Modal for map -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">close x</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Route for the request</h4>
                      </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" id="startLat" name="test" value="initial" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="startLong" name="test1" value="initial" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="endLat" name="test2" value="initial" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="endLong" name="test3" value="initial" />
                    <pre id="distance_duration"></pre>
                    
                    
                    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:400px; margin:auto; border: 5px solid #73AD21; padding: 15px;"></div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <!--Modal end -->
              </div>
        </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this gave a good understanding.
You can use php to make the table dynamic and get data for the map.